# How to get data from multiple tables in one row

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am looking for a way to get the table name and description field from all tables in my database that start with T_. What I have up till now is this:

```
DECLARE @tables TABLE(table_name VARCHAR(100), column_name VARCHAR(100), row INT); 

INSERT INTO @tables (table_name, column_name, row)
   SELECT
       tables.name AS table_name,
       columns.name AS column_name,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tables.name)
   FROM 
       sys.tables
   INNER JOIN 
       sys.columns ON tables.object_id =  columns.object_id
   WHERE 
       tables.name LIKE 'T_%' AND columns.name = 'DESCRIPTION'

DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @count INT

SELECT @i = MIN(row) -1, @count = MAX(row) 
FROM @tables

WHILE @i < @count
BEGIN
    SELECT @i = @i + 1
    DECLARE @q VARCHAR(400)
    SELECT @q = 'SELECT  ''' + (SELECT table_name FROM @tables WHERE row = @i) + ''' AS TABLE_NAME, '+ (SELECT column_name FROM @tables WHERE row = @i) + ' FROM ' + (SELECT table_name FROM @tables WHERE row = @i)
    EXEC(@q)
END
```

This results in the data I need, however in multiple tables. How can I get that data in one table?

Comment: How about storing the result set in a #temp table and selecting it after the end of while loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Build the SELECT statements
- Add UNION ALL for all except the first row at the start

  - Easier than adding to the endexcept for the last row...
- Use the XML PATH technique to concat rows into one string

Tested code:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @base nvarchar(max) = '';

SET @SQL = 
    (
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN X.rn >= 2 THEN ' UNION ALL ' ELSE '' END + X.stmt
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            @base + 'SELECT ''' + t.name + ''' AS table_name, ' + c.name + ' FROM ' + t.name AS stmt,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.object_id) AS rn
        FROM 
            sys.tables t
            INNER JOIN
            sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
        WHERE 
            t.name LIKE 'T%' AND c.name = 'DESCRIPTION'
        ) X
    ORDER BY X.rn
    FOR XML PATH ('')
    );
PRINT @sql;
EXEC (@sql);
```

SQL Server 2012+ version:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @base nvarchar(max) = '';

SET @SQL = 
    (
    SELECT 
        CONCAT(CASE WHEN X.rn >= 2 THEN ' UNION ALL ' ELSE '' END, X.stmt)
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            CONCAT(@base, 'SELECT ''', t.name , ''' AS table_name, ', c.name, ' FROM ', t.name) AS stmt,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.object_id) AS rn
        FROM 
            sys.tables t
            INNER JOIN
            sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
        WHERE 
            t.name LIKE 'T%' AND c.name = 'DESCRIPTION'
        ) X
    ORDER BY X.rn
    FOR XML PATH ('')
    );
PRINT @sql;
EXEC (@sql);
```